# Django Block URL by Username

Tags: python, django, url

Excuse me if I'm not very direct about what I'm talking about or need, I'm fairly new to django/python and am still in the process of understanding things.

I am creating a webapp with Django where a user will sign up, log in, create a new entry, save it, and view/edit it. Think of it as a personal diary that should be only accessible to the user who wrote it.

I've gotten pretty far in this and am using filtering in the ListView, but someone could easily use url manipulation to find other users entries.

Such that User A posts entry 4 at site.com/entry/4 and then user B is able to type that in and see the entry.

How can I go about restricting the url to only the user who posted it?

Thanks for any help, and again sorry if I'm not giving enough information or I'm not clear on what I am talking about!

Comment: check if the viewer of the site is the owner or even has the rights to see the page. For example in your views.py file you could write `if request.user == postOwner:(show post)....else:(send a 404 or redirect or whatever)` in your models.py (where you have the post entry) you make a field `postOwner = models.OneToOne/ForeignKey(User...)`

Comment: Thank you!  I figured it out! works great.